# Creating a JSON object in JavaScript dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, worklight-adapters

I need to create a JSON object dynamically in JavaScript using a for loop. I have tried using the `array.Push` method but it is not working. I am only getting the first value getting stored. The remaining values of the iteration are not getting stored.

This is what I am trying:

```
var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var username = drlist.reportees[i].name;
        var think40 = getthink40(n,m);
        if (think40.isSuccessful){
            var result = think40.array;
            var length = result.length;
            var tes= 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < length-1; j++){
                tes = tes + parseFloat(result[j].duration);
            }
            var hours = tes/60;
            var think = (hours/40)*100;
            if (think > 100)
                {
                think =100;
                }
            array.push( {
                    name: username,
                    hours: think
                });
                }
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post what you have tried?

Comment: var myData = [];
rows.each(function (index) {
    var obj = { 
        id: $this.find('.elementOne').val(),
        name: $this.find('.elementTwo').text()
    };
    myData.push(obj);
});
I had this as an example and pushed the values to the json array and retrun but I get only the first value of the loop

Comment: you can/should edit the question with your code instead of commenting it

Comment: JSON is a **language-independent, textual** data format, like XML or CSV. What you are trying to do is creating an array of objects. That has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
var jsonArray = [];
function test (){
for (var i=0; i<3;i++)
{
   var jsonObject = {'a':1, 'b':2}; jsonArray.push(jsonObject);
}
return jsonArray;
}
```

Note : You are returning the jsonObject instead of jsonArray. You should probably return the jsonArray.

Comment: Error 500: Failed to write the response:Adapter invocation returned an invalid result. It should return a JSON object.  when I try the above code I am getting this error code

Comment: @GopiNath I think you have a problem with this condition if(think40.isSuccessful). I think this returns false for 3 items and for only one item the condition is true. That might be the reason for you to get one item. Can you please put a console.log and check what think40.isSuccessful is returning for each item?

Comment: is there anyway to debug line by line for worklight adapters? I am not able to debug it using firebug

Answer (score 0):

Creating and manipulating a JSON object in JavaScript is not very different from any other type of object, but does have a few limitations. These are primarily around the data types JSON supports and the two most notable are a lack of dates and functions.

JavaScript objects can contain almost anything (increasingly so with ES6 and symbols) but JSON is a limited subset of that. The [JSON spec](http://json.org/) is short and easy to read (complete with pictures!), so I would recommend starting there. As you'll see in the spec, the value types include strings, numbers, objects, array, boolean keywords, and null. There is no support for dates -- easily worked around by formatting them as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings -- or functions.

To turn a valid JavaScript object into the final JSON form involves a limited amount of string formatting and escaping. Most modern browsers have a [global `JSON` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for doing that, providing both parse and render (`stringify`) methods. This is your [codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) and the first and final step when manipulating JSON.

In your example, you would build the object as normal, assigning properties (`foo.bar = 3`) as necessary. At the very end, to return the JSON (which is really just a string in JS), you would take the object you've created and pass it to `JSON.stringify`. This will produce a valid, safe, escaped JSON string suitable for passing to web services and other scripts.